# Spring security: multiple security configurations and regexmatcher

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm trying to secure multiple endponts in my home project.
Like, I have admin, who have access to /admin endpoints with basic auth;

I have /books/whitemagic, /books/darkmagic and scripts/darkmagic secured by oauth2;

And other endpoints, secured by jwt token.

So

```
//@Order(1)
//admin
http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher(homeUrl + "/admin/**")
                .authorizeRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

```
//@Order(2)
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                        .regexMatchers(".*darkmagic|whitemagic.*")
                        .authenticated())
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                    .jwt(jwtConfigurer ->
                            jwtConfigurer.decoder(JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuerUri)));
```

and

```
//@Order(3)
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .addFilterBefore(filterPerRequest, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
```

How do I see it: endpoint /books/dummymagic should be processed in third configuration, but */darkmagic and */whitemagic - in second. But! Right now /dummymagic is trying to authorize by oauth. What am I doing wrong? Do I user .regexMatcher incorrectly? Only /darkmagic/ and /whitemagic should be secured by oauth.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in my regex. I should have used braces () for grouping.